# Flex wrap reverse break?

Tags: css, flexbox

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex>div {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.a {
  background-color: green;
}

.b {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.c {
  background-color: red;
}

.d {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="d">D</div>
</div>
```

When the window is wide, the code above looks like this:

[image]

When it's small, it looks like this:

[image]

This is the wrapping behavior I want, but instead of D (purple) being full-width, I want A (green) to be full-width and B,C,D should be on the 2nd line.

`flex-wrap: wrap-reverse; flex-direction: row-reverse` almost works, but it also reverses the order of the items, which I don't want.

Any way to make this work?

Comment: media query? ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'd prefer not. Would have to hardcode a lot of stuff. I also have a sidebar that's on its own media query so that complicates it more.

Comment: then you should wrap BCD in a div .. or you are not allowed to edit the HTML?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I can edit the HTML if I need to, I just prefer not to make special exceptions where possible.

Comment: updated my answer with a more generic solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider the order property like below:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.flex>div {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.a {
  background-color: green;
  order:3;
}

.b {
  background-color: yellow;
  order:2;
}

.c {
  background-color: red;
  order:1;
}

.d {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="d">D</div>
</div>
```

In case of a dynamic content (the number of elements is unknown, you can consider `nth-last-child` like below. A code that you can easily generate using SASS/LESS

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.flex>div {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 100px;
  color:#fff;
}
.flex>div:nth-last-child(1) {order:1}
.flex>div:nth-last-child(2) {order:2}
.flex>div:nth-last-child(3) {order:3}
.flex>div:nth-last-child(4) {order:4}
.flex>div:nth-last-child(5) {order:5}
.flex>div:nth-last-child(6) {order:6}
.flex>div:nth-last-child(7) {order:7}
.flex>div:nth-last-child(8) {order:8}
.flex>div:nth-last-child(9) {order:9}
.flex>div:nth-last-child(10) {order:10}
/*.flex>div:nth-last-child(N) {order:N} */

.flex>div:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: green;
}
.flex>div:nth-child(even){
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>E</div>
  <div>F</div>
  <div>G</div>
  <div>H</div>
  <div>I</div>
  <div>J</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the HTML and then reverse it again with CSS:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.flex>div {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.a {
  background-color: green;
}

.b {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.c {
  background-color: red;
}

.d {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="d">D</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="a">A</div>
</div>
```

[image]

It's not my preferred solution because now the content is tied to the styling, but it works.