# How to change line break order when using bidi-override and right-to-left direction with CSS?

Tags: css, right-to-left, direction

I'm using a little script which hides mail addresses using the fact that you can reverse text by using [`unicode-bidi: bidi-override`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi#syntax) and [`direction: rtl`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction#syntax).

```html
<span>
    <span>moc.e</span>
    <span>ussi-</span>
    <span>kaerb</span>
    <span>-enil</span>
    <span>@sser</span>
    <span>dda-l</span>
    <span>iam-t</span>
    <span>set</span>
</span>
```

With the following output:

```
test-mail-address@line-break-issue.com
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work when the mail address is too long and contains a line-break:

[image: screenshot line break issue]

The reverse text direction causes that the end of the mail address comes before the line break:

```
-break-issue.com
test-mail-address@line
```

**Check out the code snippet:**

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: small;
}

.small {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 170px;
}

.big {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 280px;
}

strong {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

span.eeb-rtl {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override !important;
  direction: rtl !important;
  display: inline !important;
}

span.eeb-rtl span.eeb-sd {
  display: inline !important;
  padding-left: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="small">
  <strong>Small container</strong>
  <span class="eeb eeb-rtl">
    <span class="eeb-sd">moc.e</span><span class="eeb-sd">ussi-</span><span class="eeb-sd">kaerb</span><span class="eeb-sd">-enil</span><span class="eeb-sd">@sser</span><span class="eeb-sd">dda-l</span><span class="eeb-sd">iam-t</span><span class="eeb-sd">set</span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="big">
  <strong>Big container</strong>
  <span class="eeb eeb-rtl">
    <span class="eeb-sd">moc.e</span><span class="eeb-sd">ussi-</span><span class="eeb-sd">kaerb</span><span class="eeb-sd">-enil</span><span class="eeb-sd">@sser</span><span class="eeb-sd">dda-l</span><span class="eeb-sd">iam-t</span><span class="eeb-sd">set</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Is there any CSS option to correct the line breaking order in a small container?

The result should be:

```
test-mail-address@line-
break-issue.com
```

Comment: I think you can try "white-space: nowrap; overflow-x: scroll;" to the ".small" container. It is a solution to at least show the content in correct order but the scrolling may not be preferable by you, I understand that.

Comment: @Md.RakibulIslam thx for your comment. Your suggestion could be also a way to handle it, but it breaks in most cases the layout and was not the question asked here. I want a solution which works with the line break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very dirty solution but hey it works `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` . I changed the classnames because I was having a hard time following the code btw.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: small;
}

.small {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 170px;
}

.big {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 280px;
}

strong {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}



.text-piece {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
}

/* Add enough to cover all of your segments */
.text-piece:nth-last-child(1) {order:1}
.text-piece:nth-last-child(2) {order:2}
.text-piece:nth-last-child(3) {order:3}
.text-piece:nth-last-child(4) {order:4}
.text-piece:nth-last-child(5) {order:5}
.text-piece:nth-last-child(6) {order:6}
.text-piece:nth-last-child(7) {order:7}
.text-piece:nth-last-child(8) {order:8}
.text-piece:nth-last-child(9) {order:9}
.text-piece:nth-last-child(10) {order:10}

.wrapper-span {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="small">
  <strong>Small container</strong>
  <span class="wrapper-span">
    <span class="text-piece">moc.e</span><span class="text-piece">ussi-</span><span class="text-piece">kaerb</span><span class="text-piece">-enil</span><span class="text-piece">@sser</span><span class="text-piece">dda-l</span><span class="text-piece">iam-t</span><span class="text-piece">set</span>
</div>
<div class="big">
  <strong>Big container</strong>
  <span class="wrapper-span">
    <span class="text-piece">moc.e</span><span class="text-piece">ussi-</span><span class="text-piece">kaerb</span><span class="text-piece">-enil</span><span class="text-piece">@sser</span><span class="text-piece">dda-l</span><span class="text-piece">iam-t</span><span class="text-piece">set</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, cool solution, I tried already a lot with `display: flex;` but I couldn't find a working solution. And nice trick to use `:nth-last-child`!

Comment: Thanks! I got the idea from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64518633/flex-wrap-reverse-break)

Comment: Have been there before ;-) just couldn't apply it correctly!

Comment: I found two little downsides of the `flex` solution, 1) even as `inline-flex` it creates a block-like-element around the hole address, that Pseudo-elements like fancy underlines don't work the same. 2) Further, it doesn't really use hyphens to break the address but breaks it after each "flex-child". But hey, still all better than before!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to prevent web scraping, so you're displaying email like this. If you are already using "little script", the best solution is to improve it. With your permission I am trying to reproduce your script. I'm giving you a javascript code example but you can easily transfer to any other programming language like php, becase I think this one should happen on the backend side.

```js
const email = 'test-mail-address@line-break-issue.com';

small.innerHTML = convertEmail(email);
big.innerHTML = convertEmail(email);

function convertEmail(email) {
  return '<span class="email">' + 
    email.split('')
         .reverse()
         .join('')
         .match(/.{1,5}/g)
         .map( (el, index) => `<span style="order:${index * -1}">${el}</span>` )
         .join('')
  + '</span>';
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  gap: 16px;
}

#small {
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 170px;
}

#big {
  border: solid 1px green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.email {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.email span {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<div id="small"></div>
<div id="big"></div>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, but that's acutely the same solution as from [Zachiah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76582747/3001970). The script which writes the HMTL Code I have already, and it's actually even a little more complex to obscure the mail even more.